# Is this happening because event is integer type?

Tags: python, events, pygame

[event.key doesnt work. I put this code to see if c its printed when i press K_LEFT and nothing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISrAS.png)

```
if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN) and (event.type==pygame.K_LEFT):
      pXchange=-0.3
      print ('c')
    if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN) and (event.type==pygame.K_RIGHT):
      pXchange=0.3  
      print ('c')
```

[I tried this way and still not working. The '.key' from "event.key" is white. Should it be like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDxrB.png)

Comment: The `event.type` cannot be equal to `KEYDOWN` and `K_LEFT` at the same time (unless `KEYDOWN` and `K_LEFT` are the same, obviously).

Comment: Your second comparison should be `event.key==pygame.K_LEFT`

Comment: I tried this way too, it doesn't work either. while running:
  pygame.display.update()
  event=pygame.event.poll()
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running=False
      pygame.QUIT
    if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
       if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
         pXchange=-0.3
         print ('c')
    if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
       if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
         pXchange=0.3